# Access files/ folders remotely by authentication via browser/ web

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, iis, remote-access

We have some requirements where we want to allow our clients/ users to download files/ folders from our file server via browser/ web.

We have a many different directories created on our file server which is mapped to different clients. Which means that, every client has its own directory on our server. We have a main (root) directory for every single client/user. Which means that, every client’s files/folder are created under their respective main directory.

The only thing we need be sure is, whenever our client make a request to access/ download file, first we need to validate their credential (username/password are stored in our SQL server DB) and then we need to allow only those folder which is mapped for specific folder. (The folder mapping is again stored in our SQL server DB)

Which means that, after applying the credential by user/clients, they can only access their directory/ files. They cannot access other’s files/ directory.

Would anybody please do let me know how would I achieve this? All the suggestions would be appreciated highly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since different users need to be authorized to access different directories, you cannot expose your files directly on the web.

Build a simple login with a custome [MembershipProivder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). That will allow you to autenticate against your database.

Since you know which directories the user has access to, you can fetch a listing of files and folders and present it in a ListView to the user.

You can write a [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx) to check user authorization and then serve the files to them.

Comment: Don't it create heavy operations for accessing directory? I was thinking if is there any way like directory browsing with IIS.. something like that??

Comment: Security is a necessary evil. If implemented properly, it won't be very heavy though. While directory browsing will list the files, IIS does not pass all file requests through asp.net. So if your content is secure, don't leave it in publicly exposed directories